# Re-render React Swiper Component

Tags: react-native

I want to play a audio on card, when click on the play icon, it plays, i update player state to playing and want to change play icon to pause icon. But cant re-render the card. I have read https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper/issues/153  but no solution, how to solve this ?

```
  setPlay2(index, sound, stopper = false) {
....
  this.setState({
    playing: 'playing',
  });
.....
}

const {
   playing
} = this.state;

 ....

<Swiper
 ref={(swiper) => {
    this.swiper = swiper;
}}
  cards={data}
   cardIndex={cardIndex}
    renderCard={card => (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setPlay2()}>
            {
              playing === 'playing' ? (
      <Image source={require('@images/BasicAppMenu/pause.png')} style={{ height: 32, width: 32 }} />
                     ) : (
       <Image source=  {require('@images/BasicAppMenu/play.png')} style={{ height: 32, width: 32 
}} />
                             )
      }
  </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
 )}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to check `playing` within the `<TouchableOpacity>` element - is this `this.state.playing` ? You've not included all the code.

If not, this may work?

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setPlay2()}>
        {
          this.state.playing === 'playing' ? (
  <Image source={require('@images/BasicAppMenu/pause.png')} style={{ height: 32, width: 
    32 }} />
                 ) : (
   <Image source=  {require('@images/BasicAppMenu/play.png')} style={{ height: 32, 
     width: 32 
    }} />
                         )
  }
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: i edited the source code,     i have `const {
   playing
} = this.state;` before swiper.